# $scope.$watch on parent controller does not trigger on child ng-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Use Case

Using a `select` that is bound to a controller variable, whenever, the variable exists in the parent controller and a `$watch` is created on that variable in the parent, the parent `$watch` does not fire. **Why does this happen?**

### Code

#### Random Data Generator Utility Function

This code is not important, but included for clarity.

```
function populate(x) {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        items.push( { label: 'item ' + i,
                     data: { value: 'some value ' + i },
                     id: i });
    }
    return items;
};
```

#### Parent Controller

```
function parent($scope) {
  $scope.items = populate(10);
  $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
  $scope.fired = 0;

  $scope.$watch('selected.id', function(id) {
      $scope.fired++;
  });
};
```

#### Child Controller

```
function child($scope) {

};
```

#### Scenario 1

This scenario works as described. In this case, the variable `$scope.fired` will be incremented whenever the user changes the value of the select. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/t3urd/1/)

View

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="parent">
        <select ng-model="selected"
                ng-options="item as item.label for item in items">
        </select>
        <pre>
            {{ fired | json }}
        </pre>
        <pre>
            {{ selected | json }}
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Scenario 2

In the following scenario, the `$watch` will **not** trigger in the parent. However, if the `$watch` is moved to the child controller, it will fire. **Note**: the change is on line 3 compared to above code. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/t3urd/2/)

View

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="parent">
        <div ng-controller="child">
            <select ng-model="selected"
                    ng-options="item as item.label for item in items">
            </select>
            <pre>
                {{ fired | json }}
            </pre>
            <pre>
                {{ selected | json }}
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Question

Why does the inclusion of the child controller cause the `$watch` to not trigger, even though the child controller inherits the `$scope`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent's `selected` is not changing itself. The child scope's `selected` is. That's why the watch is not working as you would expect it to. This is due to prototypal inheritance.

The `$watch` itself should be defined in the children scope, regardless of the parent scope being the one declaring it on the first place.

Comment: Oh man! Prototypical inheritance! So the child controller creates only a copy of the fields and methods, but not the event listeners and watches?

Comment: It does not create a copy of the fields. When it looks for the field, it walks up the prototype chain and returns a reference (if found)

Comment: @Gamb I ran a quick [test](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/t3urd/4/), is it because `ng-select` creates an isolated scope? I don't understand the `increase()` function will update the Parent's `fired`. It appears they both share the same `fired`, but have their own `selected`.

Comment: @Pete As a matter of fact, seems to be restricted to the closest scope (the child, in this case). If you changed the `ng-model` attribute to `$parent.selected` now both controllers will have the updated value, and the watch will work as well (your counter will be increased two times). Prototypical inheritance kicks in when you point at the parent directly.

Comment: @Gamb Did some reading on prototypical inheritance last night and it's starting to clear up. Found some of the misunderstandings I had  due to my background in classical inheritance. I'm beginning to understand the power and scope (pun intended) of this. Thanks for your explanations, it's very helpful.